What do the Apollo crew mean by "you're five square"
If you watch the Apollo 15 splashdown footage,
you would notice (with CC on) that after the recovery team says "Apollo 15, Apollo 15 this is recovery" one of the astronauts replies "Rog, Recovery, 15, You're Five Square" (from 0:08)
I tried googling the meaning but nothing matched the context, can anyone tell me what they mean by this?

I do not know whether this question has a stupidly obvious answer, I feel it may be closed but I am unable to find an answer I trust.

Un sourced, but suspect it is a variant of five by five https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/five-by-five which a math nerd has noticed is five squared (25).

... which makes it perfectly sensible for a two-dimensional rating system to be described as "five squared" Instead of "five by five". @user71659

@GremlinWranger  The trouble with that is that 'the original' is essentially "Five AND Five" no multiplication in sight. In my day, we would have written it as "five/five" ...

As GremlinWranger notes in a comment, it's short for "Five by Five" which means "loud and clear", with each of signal strength and readability (how the signal level compares to the noise level) expressed on a scale from zero to five.
The phrase - usually in its longer form, or sometimes just "Five by" - appears quite often in the Apollo Flight Journal and Apollo Lunar Surface Journal, e.g. apropos of the Apollo 11 landing:

102:17:27 Aldrin: Houston, Eagle. How do you read?
102:17:29 Duke: Five-by, Eagle. We're standing by for your burn report. Over.
[Armstrong - "They are referring to the strength and clarity of the signal on a scale of five. 'Five by five' meant 'loud and clear."]


...and for Ham Radio operators, it's 5 by 9 (S-9 on the signal strength meter)

A phrase also notably used in the movie Aliens and repeated by the dropship pilots in Starcraft.  "In the pipe, five by five." -- meaning they're within the roughly circular approach path and receiving guidance signals clearly.
